# Движение картинки в стиле "Змейки" вдоль стенок блока jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Помогите реализовать движения нескольких блоков в стиле змейки по кругу вдоль краев поля
Пример с одной картинкой, который я сделал можно посмотреть здесь => http://vahminator.org.ua/test/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout("animation()",300);
    });

    function animation(){ 
        box();

    }

 function box(){
$("#box").animate({opacity: "1", left: "+=720"}, 2000)
        .animate({opacity: "1", top: "+=500"}, 1000)
        .animate({opacity: "1", left: "0"}, 2000)
        .animate({top: "0"}, 1000)
        setTimeout("box()",6000);
}
```

HTML  код

```
<div id="wrapper">

   <div id="content">

<div id="box"></div>  <!-- Бегающий блок -->

            <div class="carousel">
                <img src="images/1.png">
                <img src="images/2.png">
                <img src="images/3.png">
                <img src="images/4.png">
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос то?

Comment: в том что не получается запустить более одной картинки. В примере одна картинка "бегает" по квадрату, а нужно более 16...

Comment: А что за, простите, извращенство со вложенной функцией в animate(), где кроме box() ничего не происходит? И опасити зачем, если он не меняется? А вообще, проблема где-то на уровне CSS.

Comment: Перепишите

    setTimeout("animation()",300);
    // на
    setTimeout( animation, 300 );

и никогда так больше не делайте

`setTimeout("box()",6000);`, естественно, аналогично, а то понаписывают такого вот Г и рассказывают потом какой JS медленный, у меня все тормозит и т.д. :)